# Use multiple onClick event listeners in one component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

Below is `App.js`

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import MsgState from './components/MsgState';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MsgState /> {/* made one event listener */}
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

In `App.js` file I make one component `MsgState` and that JS file as shown below. In `MsgState.js` file I made 2 state msg and btn and 2 `setState` functions, I wanted that if I click subscribe button then both state change but only 1 event listener works.
Below is `MsgState.js`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class MsgState extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      msg: 'Welcome to all Visitors',
      btn: 'Subscribe',
    };
  }

  changeMsg() {
    this.setState({
      msg: 'Thanks',
    });
  }

  changeBtn() {
    this.setState({
      btn: 'Subscribed..!!!',
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.msg}</h1>
        <button onClick={(() => this.changeMsg(), () => this.changeBtn())}>{this.state.btn}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MsgState;
```

If I click subscribe button then only one event listener works that is `changeBtn`. I wanted that both event listener works while I click subscribe button please help...

Answer (score 1):

```
onClick={function(event){ func1(); func2()}}
```

Comment: i am not getting

Comment: you can call your functions like above. change func1 and func2 with your function names

Answer (score 1):

Please change your code as

```
onClick={
       () =>{
        this.changeMsg()
        this.changeBtn()
        } 
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you need to call them separately. There can be way to handle this inside one function only. Further extra conditions can be checked. For Example:

```
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.msg}</h1>
                <button 
                onClick={
                    () => this.clickListener(),
                }>
                    {this.state.btn}
                </button>
            </div>    
            )
    }
```

Now you can write clickListener to call both functions

```
clickListener(){
           this.changeMsg();
           this.changeBtn(); // Extra conditions if call both or only one function.
        }
```

Or setting state in a single function (Will save ONE render cycle as well)

```
clickListener(){
          this.setState(
            {
                msg: "Thanks",
                btn: "Subscribed..!!!"
            }
        )
        }
```